# Profile data are not saved for custom user model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, registration

I'm new to python and I'm trying to make user registration that is extend from user creation model, I created profile model with the fields I want and saved the profile object with signal when user is saved, the profile is created successfully and linked with the user but profile data is not saved (in this example: jobtitle, company, phone)are empty

in model.py

```
class profile (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    jobTitle = models.CharField(max_length = 100,default ='')
    phonenumber = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True, help_text='Contact phone number', default ='')


@receiver(post_save, sender = User)
def create_user_profile( sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile.objects.create(user = instance)
    instance.profile.save()

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

in forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required= True)
    company = forms.CharField(required = True)
    phonenumber = PhoneNumberField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': ('Phone')}), label=("Phone number"), required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required = True)
    jobTitle = forms.CharField(required = True)


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2',
            'company',
            'jobTitle'
            ]

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserRegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()


        return user
```

in views.py

```
#User register
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            UserProfile = user.profile
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            company = form.cleaned_data.get('company')
            jobTitle = form.cleaned_data.get('jobTitle')
            phonenumber = form.cleaned_data.get('phonenumber')
            UserProfile.save()

            messages.success(request, f'Account is created for {username}!')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
            form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

so can you help me to understand what is causing this issue? I'm expecting to save the inserted values when registering into the profile model.

Thank you

Comment: Are your @reciever decorators getting called?

Comment: apparently they are not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the second `@receiver(post_save, sender=User)`, it's useless (it's always done in the #1 profile).

When you do `user = form.save()`, the signal is raised, creating an *empty* `profile`.

So, just after `user = form.save()`, get the profile that has been created through the signal, like:

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
company = form.cleaned_data.get('company')
jobTitle = form.cleaned_data.get('jobTitle')
phonenumber = form.cleaned_data.get('phonenumber')
profile.save()
```

And my advice: read PEP8 of Python: class always "UpCase", variable always lower_case.

Comment: Thank you for your help but still doesn't save any values when I check it from admin side

Answer (score 0):

You need to also import signals in app to let django know about your implementation.

You can implement it in following manner:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```